# passing data to a view laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Just getting to mvc frameworks and im trying to pass data to my view using blade template engine.

here's my routes file

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
```

my PagesController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller {

    public function index() {

        return view('index');

        $url = 'example.com';
    }

    public function about() {


        return 'hello';


    }

}
```

my index.blade.php file

```
<h1>{{ $url }}</h1>
```

I get the Undefined variable: url error message. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public function index() {
   $url = 'example.com';
   return view('index', ['url' => $url]); 
}
```

Initialize the variable and send it as a parameter to the view.

Comment: i get this error `array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array`

Comment: @helloworld try that

Answer (score 0):

you can also pass data to view by using multiple with.

```
return View::make('blog')->with('posts', $posts)->with('anotherPost',$anotherPost);
```

you can always make multiple with or can pass values via array. whatever you think is best.